# $x selector in Puppeteer doesn't work as ElementHandle in page.evaluate

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm trying to crawl a wikipedia page using puppeteer. I prefer to use the xpath syntax for selectors because I find it to be more powerful.

From the docs, it says that both the `$x` and the `$` method should return an `ElementHandle` with the `$x` method returning an array.

[$ Docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.5.0/docs/api.md#pageselector)
[$x Docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.5.0/docs/api.md#pagexexpression)

If I run my two test queries in the Chrome console on the page in question, I get identical results. If I query both selectors without trying to evaluate the result in puppeteer, I also get identical results.

[image]

The problem comes when I try to use the `evaluate` method, the ElementHandle from the $x selector doesn't seem to be correct. But I'm having a hard time to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a code example. I deconstructed the async methods into their .then.catch to help isolate the issue.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {

    const searchUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_national_football_team"
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(searchUrl);

    const xPathSelector = page.evaluate(
            el => el.outerHTML,
            await page.$x("//table[@class='infobox']//th[contains(.,'Head')]/following-sibling::td/a")[0])
        .then(
            result => console.log(result)
        ).catch( e => {
            console.log('XPath Error', e)
        })

    const normSelector = await page.evaluate(
            el => el.outerHTML,
            await page.$("#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td > a"))
        .then(
            result => console.log(result)
        ).catch( e => {
            console.log('XPath Error', e)
        })

    await browser.close()

})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you are trying to read the first element of unresolved promise not a result of it so, change:

```
await page.$x("//table[@class='infobox']//th[contains(.,'Head')]/following-sibling::td/a")[0]
```

to (look at the extra wrapping parentheses):

```
(await page.$x("//table[@class='infobox']//th[contains(.,'Head')]/following-sibling::td/a"))[0]
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up get similar help in the slack channel, but this was the root issue.